# Solve a logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I solve this logarithmic equation for $x$ without calculator?

> $\log(\sqrt{x}) = \log (x-6)$

Comment: Start with the premise that: if log(a) = log(b) then a = b

Answer (score 3):

$\log(a) = \log(b) \implies a = b$. Hence, we have
$$\sqrt{x} = x-6$$Now let $\sqrt{x}=t > 0$. We then get that
$$t = t^2-6 \implies t^2 - t -6 = 0 \implies (t-3)(t+2) = 0 \implies t= -2, +3$$But we have $t=\sqrt{x} > 0$. Hence, $t=3 \implies x = 9$.